# Apex : Safe Navigation not working

Tags: apex, safe-navigation-operator

I am replacing ternary `?` with safe navigation but not working :(, what's wrong

```
String a,b ='foo';
a = a?.b; // why not working, i want this Ex : a = a == null ? b : a; 
System.debug('a::'+a); // foo
```

Answer (score 5):

The Safe Navigation Operator (SNO), `?.`, is not really a general replacement for ternaries.

In a nutshell, the SNO mainly allows us to skip null checks and still avoid Null Pointer Exceptions.

- If the statement fragment before the SNO is null, the SNO will not evaluate the statement fragment after the SNO and will just return `null`
- If the statement fragment before the SNO is *not null*, then it acts the same as regular dot-notation

The SNO can easily replace ternaries of the form

```java
result = objectInstance != null ? objectInstace.instanceVariable : null;
result = objectInstance != null ? objectInstace.instanceMethod() : null;
```

What your usage of the SNO implies is that `a` has an instance variable `b` (not to use `b` if `a` is null, as your example assumes).

Given that, the SNO cannot replace your ternary here.